# Why did I not install the package version that I expected?

Tags: apt, python

I was looking at [Python2.7 for debian jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python2.7) since my goal was to downgrade Python 2.7.13 to 2.7.10 or lower (running on OSMC which is now on `stretch`). From its name it looked like that package was version 2.7.9.

I added `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` [according to the instructions here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/arm64/python2.7/download), and since I only had one line marked `jessie` I then proceeded with:

```
apt-get install -t jessie python2.7
```

After that was done `python --version` gave me `2.7.15+`. That's not really what I was going for.

I'm wondering where I made a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to downgrade, and that [can’t be done by setting the target release](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt_preferences.5). When considering priorities, the first rule is

> Never downgrade unless the priority of an available version exceeds 1000. ("Downgrading" is installing
>              a less recent version of a package in place of a more recent version. Note that none of APT's default
>              priorities exceeds 1000; such high priorities can only be set in the preferences file. Note also that
>              downgrading a package can be risky.)

To downgrade, the simplest approach is to specify the release alongside the package:

```
sudo apt install python2.7/jessie
```

You’ll probably need to help the resolver out by specifying other packages to downgrade simultaneously. Depending on the packages you actually have installed, it might not even be possible...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Interesting. As you hinted, that broke the system. Time for another strategy.